# remote desktop connection to access Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 8

Tags: remote-desktop

When I tried to connect Ubuntu 14.04 form Windows-8. Every went fine and I have logged into xrdp, which showed that I have successfully connected. But after that I am getting blank screen. I tried many ways (with help of Google) but couldn't succeed. Can some on help me out how to over come this problem. Thank you.